# jQuery select and submit

Tags: jquery, forms, form-submit

I'm gathering hotel booking options (date, number of nights, number of kids etc.) via a very simple set of inputs, plus ui-datepicker for the departure date.

I'm using jQuery to gather this data and then set the corresponding 'selected' attributes of options in a hidden (ugly 3rd party) form. This is all happening fine and I can see the DOM elements are being changed - i.e., the 'selected' options in the hidden form are being changed.

Finally the form is submitted, again via jQuery:

```
$("form[name=idForm]").submit();
```

THE PROBLEM: the values aren't being recognized by the form submit even tho' the options are 'selected' ok in the DOM.

Code:

```
$(".check").click(function(){
    $(".book_result").hide(); /* just to hide verification feedback*/
    var date     = $("#datepicker").val();
    var nights     = $("#book_nights").val();
    var adults    = $("#book_adults").val();
    var children        = $("#book_children").val();
    var access_code     = $("#book_access_code").val();
    if (date=='no date selected'){
        //all the code for verifying the users' input...
        return;
    }
    else {
        var newDate = date.split(' - ');
        var day         = parseInt(newDate[0]-1);
        var month         = parseInt(newDate[1]-1);
        var year         = parseInt(newDate[2]);

        var nights         = nights - 1;
        var adults         = adults - 1 ;
        var children    = children - 1;

        if (nights < 0){nights=0};
        if (adults < 0){adults=0};
        if (children < 0){children=0};

        $("#fromday option").eq(day).attr("selected", "selected");
        $("#frommonth option").eq(month).attr("selected", "selected");
        $("#fromyear option").eq(year).attr("selected", "selected");
        $("#nbdays option").eq(nights).attr("selected", "selected");
        $("#adulteresa option").eq(adults).attr("selected", "selected");
        $("#enfantresa option").eq(children).attr("selected", "selected");

        $("#fromday option").eq(day).siblings().removeAttr("selected");
        $("#frommonth option").eq(month).siblings().removeAttr("selected");
        $("#fromyear option").eq(year).siblings().removeAttr("selected");
        $("#nbdays option").eq(nights).siblings().removeAttr("selected");
        $("#adulteresa option").eq(adults).siblings().removeAttr("selected");
        $("#enfantresa option").eq(children).siblings().removeAttr("selected");

        $("#AccessCode").val(access_code);

        $("form[name=idForm]").submit();
    }
```

So, it's all really straightforward - except it's not working and I've lost nearly 2 days to it :(

It's like the the page doesn't recognize that the hidden 3rd party form's selects have been changed - I thought the form submit would have read off the tags in the DOM, no?

Any help would be great - I've searched for similar problems on SO and via google but I'm not finding the same situation really, whereby a form is being manipulated via jquery then submitted.

It's all online already (shameful, I know!) at http://www.hotelginorialduomo.com - just click 'make a booking'...

Comment: What exactly is not working? What values aren't being recognized by the form submit? Please give more accurate details.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard - the form, on submission, is obviously calling the file spec'ed in the 'action' attr of the form. The resulting query string doesn't have the values of those options marked as 'selected' in the DOM - it's just defaulting to the first option of each. Therefore, the form submit isn't picking up those values 'selected' by the jquery manipulation of the DOM...

Comment: Ha - you beat me to it - thanks Shadow Wizard! I was just typing up the answer only to discover I'm not allowed to answer my own Qs - less than 100 rep. I was posting this:OK - it's sorted...

The problem was this:

$("#fromday option").eq(day).attr("selected", "selected");

Whilst this did indeed manipulate the 'selected' attributed of the html select options, it wasn't being picked up as a changed value by the form submit. Instead this worked...

$("#fromday").val(day);

Man, I'm glad that's done!

Over n out...

S

Comment: @ShadowWizard - absolutely - the code is weird! The form is supplied by the 3rd party 'booking engine' people and it is UGLY! For that reason I've had to remake the interface and unfortunately I had to tie into their code as the form submit actually calls a javascript function in their library which in turn does the real submit. In an effort not to get caught up in their code I'd made the decision to use the 'off screen' form, just manipulating the values and 'clicking' submit via jquery.

Comment: @Scott - I've posted my comment as answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to select the value properly with such code:

```
$("#fromday").val(day);
```

For this to work, have each `<option>` with proper value, e.g. for day 2:

```
<option value="2">2</option>
```

Also, don't remove the "selected" attribute - unless you got some hidden meaning behind this.

Comment: thanks - I was just checking back old posts and found you'd added the original 'comment' answer as post - sorry for the late 'accept'. Cheers, SC

Comment: Cheers, better late than never. :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a `submit` event handler registered to your form? Something like the below might exist:

```
$("form[name=idForm]").submit(function() {
    // do things like validation
});
```

If not, you can't (AFAIK) directly trigger the jQuery `submit()` function. You've to do the below in order to submit the form:

```
$("form[name=idForm]")[0].submit();
```

Also, be sure to check [gmkv's reply on the jQuery API site](http://api.jquery.com/submit/#dsq-comment-message-106178333).

Comment: Ok - after investigation it seems your suggestions are more regarding a situation where the form just won't submit. In this problem, the forms submits no problem but it's not picking up the values of the <select> boxes - the 'selected="selected"' attributes having been set by jquery. I've tested this by simply using $("formButton").click() which submits the 'off screen' form no problem but doesn't include the 'new' selected options...

Comment: Also, sorry if I'm not managing to make the explanation so clear!.. it's kinda tricky to be coherent with the 'select, selected, option' etc.!

Comment: I'm wondering of there's a way to 'update' the form after the option 'selected' attributes have been changed - I notice that the 'off screen' select dropdowns aren't displaying the new values even when the DOM elements are changed. To do this I changed the css positioning of the 'off screen' form in firebug to bring it 'on screen', ran the form submit, checked which options had selected="selected", noticing that these didn't correspond to the values still being displayed by the html select boxes...

Comment: **SEE LAST COMMENTS ON INITIAL QUESTION FOR THE SOLUTION - CAN'T POST ANSWER TO MY OWN Q FOR ANOTHER 6 HOURS - I'VE GOT LESS THAN 100 REPUTATION.**